# 2up pdf with the toc as bookmarks

Tags: hyperref, bookmarks, ps2pdf

I left the world of postscript today, but now I wonder how to get a 2up pdf that still has the pdfbookmarks. I found pdfnup but this loses the pdfbookmarks. Is there a way to keep them? Previously I used dfips, 2up, ps2pdf.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Java project [PAX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pax) might be helpful. It works for hyperlinks, which are PDF annotations and stripped during PDF file manipulation. I don't know if it works for bookmarks too.
But i guess the answering robot of Heiko Oberdiek will come up soon after sniffing the hyperref tag! ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That works for the links (did not notice yet that they were broken too), but the bookmarks are gone. Let's wait for the robot. =;-)